# JQuery failed to change image SRC onmouseover/hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After some research, the below code should works fine to change the image source but it's not?

```
$("#li_1").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/hover_12.png");
        }, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/ori_12.png");
        });
```

**HTML Code**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css">
<style>
li{
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='wrap'>
        <div id="clickable_div">MENU</div>
            <div id="nav_menu">
                <ul class="dropDown">
                    <li id="li_1"><img src="images/ori_12.png"></li>
                    <li id="li_2"><img src="images/ori_14.png"></li>
                    <li id="li_3"><img src="images/ori_15.png"></li>
                    <li id="li_4"><img src="images/ori_16.png"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script>
        $("#li_1").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/hover_12.png");
        }, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/ori_12.png");
        });

        $('#wrap').mouseover( function(){
            $('#nav_menu').slideDown();
        });
        $('#wrap').mouseleave( function(){
            $('#nav_menu').slideUp();
        });

    </script>
</html>
```

**DEMO.CSS:**

```
#clickable_div {width:166px; background-color:#9c9c9c;}
*{margin:0; padding:0}
#nav_menu{width:166px; height:auto; background-color:#CCC;display:none;}

#wrap{ width:166px }
```

The idea is very simple. I'm trying to mouseover an element and have a dropdown feel to list the items, and for each item I hover, the image of `li` will be replaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be trying to change the `src` of the `LI` element, not the `IMG` element.
You will also need a `mouseout` event to change the image src back to normal.

Try this:

```
$("#li_1 img")
    .mouseover(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/hover_12.png");
    })
    .mouseout(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/ori_12.png");
    });
```

---

If you want it dynamic, so you don't have to add a block of code for each image, try this.

```
$('#nav_menu li img')
    .mouseover(function () {
        this.src = this.src.replace('/ori_', '/hover_');
    })
    .mouseout(function () {
        this.src = this.src.replace('/hover_', '/ori_');
    });
```